# Switching fragment - Google map V2 view not hiding

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am making an android application with several fragments. My first Fragment is composed with some elements and a viedo view like this :[image]

when i'm switching on fragment with google map view, the transaction works fine, but when i come back  on the first fragment, The map view isn't hidden fully like this :

[image]

these two fragment are allocated in the main fragmentactivity and hide/show when it's necessary like this :

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment)
{
    FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // If Active fragment is instance of AccueilFragment I hide this one  
    if(activeFragment instanceof AccueilFragment)
    {
        System.out.println("accueil fragment hide");
        trans.hide(mAccueilFragment);
    }
    // If Active fragment is instance of CataloguesFragment I hide this one 
    if(activeFragment instanceof CataloguesFragment)
    {
        System.out.println("ctalogue fragment hide");
        trans.hide(mCataloguesFragment);
    }
    // If Active fragment is instance of MagasinsFragment I hide this one 
    if(activeFragment instanceof MagasinsFragment)
    {
        System.out.println("magasins fragment hide");
        trans.hide(mMagasinsFragment);
    }
    // If Active fragment is instance of NewsFragment I hide this one 
    if(activeFragment instanceof NewsFragment)
    {
        System.out.println("news fragment hide");
        trans.hide(mNewsFragment);
    }
    mListFragments.add(fragment);
    // I set the new active fragment
    activeFragment = fragment;
    // I show it
    trans.show(fragment);
    // And I commit transaction  
    trans.commit();
}
```

It's appear that google map view isn't hidden and pass in foreground, can someone help me ?

Comment: Have you tried to `addToBackStack` and `replace` instead of `hide/show`?

Comment: no i haven't but I can, i have to find the way to do this job !

Comment: I have not used the `hide/show` for fragments, but have used strictly the `addToBackStack` and `replace` and they work nicely for me.

Comment: how do you treat replace function please ?

Comment: Use `myFragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_id_where_you_want_fragment, theFragmentToGoInThatConatiner);`